# Parse error while doing insert in mysql in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following code in php:

```
$text = 'gd'; 
$ip = '102.123.12.12';

$sql = "INSERT INTO 'database'.'table' ('text', 'ip') VALUES (:text, :ip)";
$params = ["text" => $text, "ip" => $ip];
$conn->query($sql, $params);
```

and after running that on my server I get the error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/visavie/domains/visavie.me/public_html/test/cityToDB.php on line 22 (line 22 is the one starting from $params = ["... 
What might be wrong here?

Comment: `$params = array( "text"  => $text , "ip" => $ip); ` try this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server runs an older php version that that does not support array assignment like that (you need php 5.4+ for that):

```
$params = ["text" => $text, "ip" => $ip];
```

You would need to upgrade your server or change it to:

```
$params = array("text" => $text, "ip" => $ip);
```

After this, you will run into another problem as you are using the wrong kind of quotes for your table- and column names:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'database'.'table' ('text', 'ip') VALUES (:text, :ip)";
```

Should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (`text`, `ip`) VALUES (:text, :ip)";
```

Single or double quotes are for values only, backticks for table- and column names (if necessary).

**Edit:** You are also mixing mysqli and PDO syntax. mysqli does not support placeholders like `:ip`, you need `?` and then you bind them using [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: Thanks, I used your advice and changed it to that:

$sql = "INSERT INTO database.table(text, ip) VALUES (:text, :ip)";
$params = array( "text" => $text , "ip" => $ip);
$conn->query($sql, $params);

but now I'm getting the error:

Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 2 to be long, array given  on line 23
Error: INSERT INTO database.table(text, ip) VALUES (:text, :ip)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':text, :ip)' at line 1
what can be wrong here?

Comment: Thanks a lot, one last thing-I went through it and wrote a code like this:
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO database.table(`text`, `ip`) VALUES (:name, :ip)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip);
    // insert a row
    $name = "John";
    $ip = "102.102.102.102";
    $stmt->execute();
and my table structure is: [id, text, ip, timestamp]. I want to insert only two middle variables, the rest should be handled by database (since id is primary key unique). And now I get the php error:
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: @randomuser2 I assume you switched to PDO? Anyway, you need to make sure the ID is an auto-increment value in the database.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 issues

- one usage of array notation which may not be supported by your PHP version.
  Change the array to use old style `$param = array()`
- The 2nd issue is you have invalid sql statement, get rid off single quotes for table and column names.

---

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO database.table (text, ip) VALUES (:text, :ip)";
```

Comment: Thanks! as I mentioned below, I changed it to that: $sql = "INSERT INTO database.table(text, ip) VALUES (:text, :ip)"; $params = array( "text" => $text , "ip" => $ip); $conn->query($sql, $params); but now I'm getting the error: Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 2 to be long, array given on line 23 Error: INSERT INTO database.table(text, ip) VALUES (:text, :ip) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':text, :ip)' at line 1 what can be wrong here?

Comment: If you are binding the param as array and column name then remove the place holder and use `?` instead